# Checking that $((a * b)) evaluates in my own shell

Tags: ksh, c, openbsd, posix, testing

POSIX seems to define that a shell should be able to evaluate like a calculator the expression `$(( a * b))` where `*` is a binary operator +, - or *. I programmed such a calculator for my own shell and scripted a test for it.

```
$ $((32 * 32))
$((32 * 32))
Result = 1024
```

But when I run the test I can't fetch the output (1024) from the shell. I want to test in the script that the shell actually computes the right result instead of a manual inspection. Now my test works with a manual inspection but I want to programatically check that the result is correct.

```
printf "********************* TEST Arithmetics  ... .\nYou should see the number 4096 below "
#read _
valgrind --leak-check=yes ./shell .<< EOF
echo $((64 * 64))
EOF
```

This is the output from the test:

```
********************* TEST Arithmetics  ... .
You should see the number 4096 below 'PATH' is set to /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin.
stdin is a file or a pipe

4096
==31803== 
==31803== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31803==     in use at exit: 79,725 bytes in 167 blocks
==31803==   total heap usage: 502 allocs, 335 frees, 228,175 bytes allocated
==31803== 
==31803== LEAK SUMMARY:
==31803==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31803==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31803==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31803==    still reachable: 79,725 bytes in 167 blocks
==31803==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31803== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==31803== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==31803== 
==31803== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==31803== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
==31805== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==31805== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==31805== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==31805== Command: ./shell .
==31805==
```

Update

This works, write it to file and look in the file for the number 1024.

```
#!/bin/ksh
#read _
./shell .<< EOF > tmp.txt
echo $((32*32))
EOF
```

Comment: please hint on the actual shell you are using. by default `openbsd` has `sh`, `csh` and `ksh` installed. i suspect your login user has `ksh` set as default - and therefore suggest using `sh` for the script instead.
furthermore, `POSIX` as a standard does not imply it's (proper) implementation.

Comment: I use `ksh` default OpenBSD shell and I also use default shell in Ubuntu 16 which says `bash` if I do `echo $0`. II develop with `bash` on Ubuntu to make it work first time, then I adjust the script to work with `ksh` and OpenBSD. I sync via github and build on OpenBSD in a VirtualBox. I want to learn how to link with dynamic libraries because some time BSD complained about that I linked to a static library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if [ "1024" == "$((32*32))" ]; then
    echo "The test worked"
else
    echo "The test failed"
fi
```

This ought to work; if your shell does not use `$(( ))` for arithmetic, the strings will not match.  You can also shorthand it with:

```
[ "1024" == "$((32*32))" ] || echo "I can't math!"
```

Comment: My shell can't understand reserved words yet but this will work when testing the shell from a real shell: `./my_shell .<< EOF > tmp.txt` and then look for 1024 in tmp.txt.